# width, max-width don't apply to <td>

Tags: html, css, razor

I need to set max width for my  in case text will be too long. I tried to set "width" and "max-width", but without success.

Now how it looks with the too long text.

[image: too long text]

```
<tr>
<td class="no-wrap">
<div class="grid-item-margin-left">@Html.DisplayFor(m => checkListItem.StepNumber).</div>
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(m => description)
</td>
```

My problem is in

```
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(m => description)
</td>
```

I tried this solution:

```
<td>
<p style="max-width:60ch">@description</p>
</td>
```

But the result on the second screen:

[image: text override]

UPDATE:
Thanks for advices! I tried this

```
.long-text-trim {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    max-width: 60ch;
}
```

and it works.
BUT! I have another issue: when I minimize window I want to trim text more. How to implement this?

Comment: Leave out the <p> tag unless the content of your table cell is truly a paragraph and try max-width on <table> or on all td, look here https://codepen.io/JUSEN/pen/vYKYPwz

Comment: you have three options - [hide the overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), [ellipsis the text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) or [break the word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

Answer (score 0):

That works good:

```
.long-text-trim {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    max-width: 20vw;
}
```